# Imported csv file cannot show in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv

Hi i recently imported a csv file to mysql and tried to display it on web using laravel

it does loop. but the data arent showing heres within my controller

```
$csv=tbl_name::all();<br>
return view('index')->with('csv', $csv);
```

and my blade file is:

```
@foreach($csv as $datas) <br>
  {{$datas->col1}}<br>
  {{$datas->col2}}<br>
  {{$datas->col3}}<br>
  {{$datas->col4}} <br>
  @endforeach
```

all i get is whitespaces with no text

i made a model too so i can access it from my controller but its empty

Comment: What does `$csv` look like?

Comment: can you `dd($csv)` so you're sure you're accessing it right?

Comment: i tried return $csv; and what i need is there, i dont know why  it wont show in blade

Comment: Check the database content first. Make sure all data is in each database cell and not all in the first cell or elsewhere.  You have not said anything to convince that the data was imported correctly in the first place.

Comment: What is the structure of the table? does it have those columns?